# Http resource request method and Grails server

Tags: grails, http-post

I'm building a controller which delivers image from Linux file system. And I need to force request http method.
 on gsp side I have something like :

```
<div style="background-image: url('${createLink(controller: 'customServing', action:'imageserv', params: [param1: 'foo'])}');"></div>
```

controller side is :

```
static allowedMethods = [index: 'GET',
                         imageserv: ['POST']]
```

the action look like:

```
    def imageserv = {

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos )
            ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new File(whateverPic)),'png',baos)

            byte[] imageAsByte = baos.toByteArray()

            response.setHeader('Content-length', imageAsByte.length.toString())
            response.contentType = 'image/png'
            response.outputStream << imageAsByte
            response.outputStream.flush()
    }
```

The web browser will automatically issue a request to get the background

```
image: Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/customServing/imageserv?param1=foo
Request Method:GET
```

I would have used Ajax or classic javascript to format my request, but I can't because of conception needs. (so it also implies grails remote link, or html form manually fired submit event are not valid option)

Is there any way to indicate (client side or server side) browser to issue only POST request for page resource rendering?

edit: I do have total control over context environment (Cent OS 7, Tomcat 8)

Comment: I doubt it because such a request is supposed to be a GET. POST requests are created either through an HTML form or JavaScript/AJAX. What's the purpose of forcing it to be a POST?

Comment: Well it means to limit external call/public invocation. Disabling common method which consist : right clic/copy link / sharing the link and reposting it. I don't want to forbid access with Security Credential, cookie or session, Just to limit it, so I can have better control and limit traffic over the file I can serv. But at the same time I need it to be Javascript independent, To keep service running even in special or limited environment.

Comment: Look into websockets. You can use the Web cam concept to just return image. Typically Web cam tends to poll for new images which you won't need and your image would  be your file that your trying load above. But that's again java scripts. In the definitive guide to grails Jeff builds a rest call to load images for his music store. You could also look into that and how then you put restrictions on your rest server which maybe you split app into two one doing rest images and other servicing with rest app checking request